# Multiple Time Zones in RDS

Tags: time-zone, rds

i have multiple users connecting to the same server from different time zones and countires.
the problem is that when users connect to the server they receive the time zone and language setting that are set to my own time zone.
is there a way to set it so they will get the correct time zone and language settings?

Answer (score 0):

According to [VMWare](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-7/7.13/published-desktops-applications/GUID-443F9F6D-C9CB-4CD9-A783-7CC5243FBD51.html):

> 1. On the Active Directory server, open the Group Policy
>    Management Console.
> 2. Expand your domain and Group Policy Objects.
> 3. Right-click the GPO that you created for the group policy settings and
>    select Edit.
> 4. In the Group Policy Management Editor, navigate to
>    Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows
>    Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host >
>    Device and Resource Redirection.
> 5. Enable the setting Allow time zone
>    redirection.

Note that this is just for time zones. I don't think there is a way to update language settings (locale at most, but even that I doubt).

Comment: thank you. i will check it. the time issue is the more important issue these users are having.